# XHTML file build from HTML is not showing D3.js graph, even though HTML did show it

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, xhtml

I'm trying to create an XHTML file with a D3 graph, from a previous HTML file. My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .bar {
        fill: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="d3.v4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
    <script src="bar_chart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This shows this:

[image]

However, when I turn this into XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <style>
      .bar {
        fill: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="../script/d3.v4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
    <script src="../script/bar_chart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It shows this:

[image]

This is the JS script that's generating the bar chart.

```
var dataset1 = [33, 57, 84, 21, 60];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = 200,
  width = svg.attr("width") - margin,
  height = svg.attr("height") - margin;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.5),
  yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")");

xScale.domain(dataset1);
yScale.domain([0, 100]);

g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(
    d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(function (d) {
      return "sale: " + d;
    })
  );

g.append("g").call(
  d3
    .axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
      return "$" + d;
    })
    .ticks(4)
);

g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(dataset1)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function (d) {
    return xScale(d);
  })
  .attr("y", function (d) {
    return yScale(d);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - yScale(d);
  });
```

Do you guys what I'm missing? I supposed that turning HTML into XHTML was just following some more guidelines and specifying at the top that it's an XHTML. Is D3 incompatible?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: @James there is none

Comment: Did you [validate](https://validator.w3.org/) your XHTML - it's very strict.  I don't think you have default support for the <svg> tag for example.  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: As James says, you're just missing the svg namespace. I.e. use `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400" />`